# C - trying to change values on the stack works in one case, but not in another, why is that?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, stack

I am trying to play with a c code and see how I can access elements on the stack by just changing the value of the pointer.
In the following code, I have two variables - i and f - and a pointer to f. My foolish aim (it's just playing) was to change the pointer to i, without doing it directly, and giving i the address of a function as a value.
Now, it all worked just fine, and I managed to run the function by casting i to that function type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(void)
{
    printf("Inside function\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t f = 15;
    size_t *ptr = &f;

    /*  why do I need that line??   */
    printf("i is: %p\n", &i);

    /*  pointing ptr to i   */
    ptr = (size_t *)((size_t)ptr - sizeof(size_t));

    /*  making sure I can change the value of i */
    *ptr = 12;
    printf("i should be 12: %lu\n", i);

    /*  inserting the address of function to it */
    *ptr = (size_t)function;

    /*  validating i has the same address as function   */
    printf("i has the value of:  0x%lx\n", i);
    printf("address of function: %p\n", function);

    /*  calling the function through i  */
    typedef void (*func)(void); 
    ((func)i)();    

    return (0);     
}
```

My question is, this works fine only when I first print the address of i. If I remove that line, it won't work and I'll get a segmentation fault (i still gets to have the first value it received). My guess was that it had something to do with the compiler, but what does the compiler do and why does it do it? I compile using gcc.

Thank you
(It's the first time I ever ask a question on here. I didn't know how to look up that kind of question, so I am sorry if something similar has been already posted in the past)

Comment: For x64 change this `ptr = (size_t *)((size_t)ptr - sizeof(size_t));` to `ptr = (size_t *)((char*)ptr + sizeof(size_t));` Still all this heavily depends on UB.

Comment: Note about @alk answer: "UB" means "Undefined Behavior", aka something that the compiler is free to decide for himself. Aka "don't count on it". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `printf("i is: %p\n", &i);` you are taking the address of `i`. This forces the compiler to actually *give* it an address.

Otherwise the compiler will likely notice that `size_t i = 0;` sets `i` to zero, and that never changes throughout the program. So it can just use `0` instead of `i` for the rest of the program.

Your code here

```
/*  pointing ptr to i   */
ptr = (size_t *)((size_t)ptr - sizeof(size_t));
```

makes heavy assumptions on how the compiler places variables in memory. The language doesn't say anything about this, so the compiler can do anything it wants - including not placing a variable in memory at all.

Comment: I see! I knew it had to do with the compiler, and I just wasn't sure what it was. Makes complete sense to me.

Thank you very much, that was clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  pointing ptr to i   */
ptr = (size_t *)((size_t)ptr - sizeof(size_t));
```

Whew. This won't go well, but why?

I'm gessing you have some notion that `i`, `f`, and `ptr` are locals allocated on your program's stack. That part is correct. :)

Taking that into account, you may have thought that as `a` was declared before `f`, it must also be right before in the memory space. Well... this is not something that your compiler guarantees.

The compiler has some degree of freedom (which is defined by the language standard) in order to produce better programs.

For instance, I used a debugger to have a look at the stack layout, and it turns out that using this actually work with gcc4.9.2/x86-64 platform:

```
/*  pointing ptr to i   */
ptr = (size_t *)((size_t)ptr + sizeof(size_t)); // -> "PLUS"
```

You can try this, but please **don't consider it a viable option**! This won't work for long (changing your source code even slightly could break the whole thing apart).

Instead you should use something more direct:

```
/*  pointing ptr to i   */
ptr = &i;
```

Pointer to `i`... address of `i`. As simple as that! And this will always work (well, as long as there is a variable named `i` un your scope).

To sum up: you started with a somewhat good intuition, but making this kind of thing work would rely on dark magic. Simply use the `&` adress operator. It's straightforward (the code's intent becomes clearer) and well... it just works!

---

Side note:

You use a `size_t` to point to a function. I would rather use a `void *` here.

`void *` pretty much means : *pointer to god knows what*.

Comment: Of course! I just wanted to play with the stack a bit, to see how I can access the addresses on the stack. I am well aware how to point on an address normally (and you can see from the line of ptr = &j).

I'll give a bit of a background. I read some article about the stack ("Smashing the stack") and it made me curious to try and play with the stack by myself. I didn't want to go as far as what that article described, but wanted to get a taste of it. It was just for fun.

Comment: @Sakebi If you want to see some cool stuff, there are a few scenarios to exploit stack buffer overflows. One of those requires to overwrite the return address and have you code "jump" wherever you tell it to. I'll let you check that out. :)